# How to convert list structure from one pattern to other pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to solve it by List Comprehension in Pyhon

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "cleaning_type": "Lite service",
            "service_name": "Floors",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "cleaning_type": "Lite service",
            "service_name": "Bathrooms",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "cleaning_type": "Lite service",
            "service_name": "Kitchen",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "cleaning_type": "Moving cleaning",
            "service_name": "Kitchen Including All Appliances And Cabinets",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "cleaning_type": "Moving cleaning",
            "service_name": "Shift Products",
            
        }

    ]
```

**I want this to be in the following format:**

```
 [
  {
    id: 1,
    cleaning_type: 'Lite service',
    service_name: ['Floors', 'bathroom', 'kitchen'],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    cleaning_type: 'Moving cleaning',
    service_name: ['Kitchen Including All Appliances And Cabinets','Shift Products'],
  },
]
```

I want the list in the second format like group wise. service_name will be shown under cleaning type.

Comment: You can't do this with a list comprehension. List comprehensions produce a 1-to-1 mapping between input and output, except that you can leave some elements out or the results with `if`.

Comment: How would you do it with a *normal* for loop?

Comment: @Barmar, any other way has the  solution.

Comment: Why must it be by list comprehension?

Comment: @GordonAitchJay, OK if you have other solution without list comprehension than ok.

Comment: @wwii, Yes if you have solution by for loop than okay. Actually I want to show the data in groupwise.

Comment: Create a dictionary whose keys are the cleaning type. Loop through your input, creating or adding to the element that matches the current cleaning type.

Comment: Try to explore 'defaultdict(list)`

Comment: are the ids in the result list just arbitrary, they don't have to relate to the ids in the input data at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as close as I could get to your desired format. I don't understand how you got `id` = `2` for the second item, since the `cleaning_type` of the item with an `id` of `2` is `Lite service`.

It's worth noting that keys need to be immutable types. I've just used strings directly, instead of creating variables named `id`, `cleaning_type`, and `service_name` bound to the same strings (note the lack of quotes in your example)

```py
items = [
            {
                'id': 1,
                'cleaning_type': 'Lite service',
                'service_name': 'Floors',
                
            },
            {
                'id': 2,
                'cleaning_type': 'Lite service',
                'service_name': 'Bathrooms',
                
            },
            {
                'id': 3,
                'cleaning_type': 'Lite service',
                'service_name': 'Kitchen',
                
            },
            {
                'id': 4,
                'cleaning_type': 'Moving cleaning',
                'service_name': 'Kitchen Including All Appliances And Cabinets',
                
            },
            {
                'id': 5,
                'cleaning_type': 'Moving cleaning',
                'service_name': 'Shift Products',
                
            }
        ]

items_by_type = {}
for item in items:
    cleaning_type = item['cleaning_type']
    
    # We have not yet come across this cleaning type before, so create a new dict
    if cleaning_type not in items_by_type:
        new_item = {}
        new_item['id'] = item['id']
        new_item['cleaning_type'] = cleaning_type
        new_item['service_name'] = [item['service_name']] # Note: This is a list
        items_by_type[cleaning_type] = new_item
    
    # The dict already exists, so we only need to add the cleaning type to the list that was previously created
    else:
        items_by_type[cleaning_type]['service_name'].append(item['service_name'])

# Transform to a list, since you don't want the keys
items_by_type_as_list = [d for d in items_by_type.values()]

expected_result = [
                      {
                          'id': 1, 
                          'cleaning_type': 'Lite service', 
                          'service_name': ['Floors', 'Bathrooms', 'Kitchen'], 
                      }, 
                      {
                          'id': 4, 
                          'cleaning_type': 'Moving cleaning', 
                          'service_name': ['Kitchen Including All Appliances And Cabinets', 'Shift Products'], 
                      }
                  ]
print(items_by_type_as_list == expected_result)
```

Output:

```py
True
```

Comment: `servicetype_list = Service.objects.all() `   so `items = servicetype_list `  but when i run it says: 'Service' object is not subscriptable
for this line :      `cleaning_type = item['cleaning_type']`

Comment: So at that line, `item` is of type `Service`, not of type `dict`. You'll have to post more code.